# Javascript splitting the sentence to each word but do not forget about special characters

Tags: javascript

Well, I need to split the the sentence into words and manipulate them. My problems is just the words that join with the special characters like `me,` or `do?`. I need that two words filtered without `,` or `?` or any special characters. However, I need to join back the manipulated words with the special characters as input.

Anyone can help me? Snippet code so far the sample for my question.

```js
var sentence = "Tell me, what should I do?";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.output = sentence.split(" ");
  $scope.join_back = $scope.output.join(" ");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{output}}
    <hr/>
    {{join_back}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Explode the sentence into words ->manipulate the words -> join back the manipulated words same as input words format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex to split your string.

```
sentence.split(/\s|(?=\W)/)
```

and to remove the space before punctuation use

```
$scope.output.join(" ").replace(/\s+(\W)/g, "$1");
```

```js
var sentence = "Tell me, what should I do?";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.output = sentence.split(/\s|(?=\W)/);
  $scope.join_back = $scope.output.join(" ").replace(/\s+(\W)/g, "$1");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{output}}
    <hr/>
    {{join_back}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `,` and `?` does not same position as input.

Comment: @Imran Check now.

Comment: I tried so far before was like this: `{{output | joinBy : "  "}}`. But in your case it was quite different

Comment: @Imran let me check

Comment: That's enough for the requirement @Deep. Thanks a lot.